# How to populate mat-option with elements from an array received from api

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, md-select

I have an issue and i think im missing something because i cant populate the md-option with the elements received from an API.

Here is the service.ts where i make the call and i try to retrieve the data from the API.

```
getCars(){
 this.http.get(this.rootURL+'/car/getallcars')
 .toPromise()
 .then(res => this.carList = res as Cars[]);
}
```

Basically the api returns something like this:

```
{
"id": "b49981fc-730e-49fc-b5e4-0159f4b42c9d",
"brand": "Mercedes",
"model": "G-Klasse",
"mileage": 19000,
"isAvailable": true
}
```

In the html i have like this:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
<mat-label>Field</mat-label>
<mat-select name="myField"  #brand="ngModel [(ngModel)]="service.formData.brand">
<mat-option *ngFor ="let car of carList" [value]="car.id" >{{car.brand}}</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Here comes the issue.. I dont know how should i write in the component.ts to take the elements from API and populate this mat-option.

Comment: Hello you mean you don't know how to get the data from API right?

Comment: The data from the API i think i get in service.ts. What i need to do is to get the data from the api into an array of 'Car' type and after that to populate the mat-option with the elements from that array.

Comment: try `res.data` instead of `res`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please try with below code?

in your **service.ts** file replace below code

```
getCars(){
  return this.http.get(this.rootURL+'/car/getallcars');
}
```

In your component.ts file

```
ngOnInit() {
    if (!this.service.formData) {
        this.resetForm();
    }
    this.getCarsData();
}

cars: any = [];
getCarsData(): void{
    this.service.getCars().subscribe(data => {
       console.log(data);
       this.cars = data;
    });
}
```

In your component.html file

```
<mat-label>Field</mat-label>
<mat-select name="myField"  #brand="ngModel [(ngModel)]="service.formData.brand">
  <mat-option *ngFor ="let car of cars" [value]="car.id" >{{car.brand}}</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Comment: Is working! Thank you so much for your effort!!

Answer (score 0):

you can do it that way

- create a class Car

```
export class Car {
 id: string,
 brand: string, 
 model: string,
 mileage: number,
 isAvailable: boolean
 constructor(data) {
    this.id = data.id;
    this.brand = data.brand;
    this.model =  data.model;
    this.mileage = data.number;
    this.isAvailable = data.isAvailable;
 }
}
```

- then import class in your service and use it.

```
getCars(){
 this.http.get(this.rootURL+'/car/getallcars')
 .toPromise()
 .then(res => {
     this.carList = res.data.map(car => new Car(car))
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I read your answers above and I feel that can be a better way, here my opinion:

*In your models create a new interface:*
**car.ts**

```
export interface Car{
 id: string,
 brand: string, 
 model: string,
 mileage: number,
 isAvailable: boolean
}
```

**service.ts:**

```
getCars(): Observable<Car[]> {
  return this.http.get(this.rootURL+'/car/getallcars');
}
```

**component.ts:**

```
import { Car} from 'src/app/shared/model/car';
import { CarService } from 'src/app/shared/service/car.service.ts';

export class CarComponent implements OnInit {
 

    cars: Car[];
    selected: string;

    constructor(private carservice: CarService) { }  

    ngOnInit(): void {
       this.carService.getCars().subscribe(data => {
         this.cars = data;
      })
     }

}
```

**In your template**

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
<mat-label>Field</mat-label>
<mat-select name="myField"  #brand="ngModel [(ngModel)]="selected">
<mat-option *ngFor ="let car of cars" [value]="car.id" >{{car.brand}}</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```